# one row up if. macro

Tags: vba, excel, row

I have data like this.

[image]

I need to take all numbers by "ELEVATION\AZIMUTH" and pull them one row up.
Can any one can show me how to do that with vba?

Comment: You can learn how to do that by yourself. Just start recording a macro and do what you want to do in your worksheet.

Comment: you want to move the data in rows that are "labeled" _ELEVATION\AZIMUTH_ and move the data into the row above each of those rows ... the top _ELEVATION\AZIMUTH_ data moves into _AZIMUTH_ row ... the next _ELEVATION\AZIMUTH_ data moves into _ELEVATION_ and so on ......... looking at your sheet, i do not think that is what you actually want  .... is that what you are asking to do ?

Comment: yea it is what i want @jsotola. I have liek this rows about 3000.. so i need to find all numbers by ELEVATION\AZIMUTH and move them one row up. After that i will delete row with ELEVATION\AZIMUTH

Comment: @Egan Wolf. then i recording macro it is taking coordinates. I have a lot of rows like this.. i need loop function i believe

Comment: No, you just need to insert one cell in column A (and move data down) or delete cells B3:(lastColumn)3 (and move data up).

Comment: i cant touch rows with TEST DATE_TIME and row with date. So i can' t move all data down, or move all data up. @Egan Wolf

Comment: looks like you could use a blank row above each _TEST DATE_TIME_ just to make it easier to read, or you could color _TEST DATE_TIME_ row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

untested

```
dim c as range
for each c in range("A2:5000").cells
  if c.value = "ELEVATION\AZIMUTH" then c.offset(0,1).resize(1,100).cut c.offset(-1,1)
next c
```